How to implement IronSource ad network in react native?
I'm integrating ironsource sdk in my react native android app but face this issue:
**What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.7.0.
Required by:
project :app
> Could not resolve com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.7.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://android-sdk.is.com/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/7.7.0/mediationsdk-7.7.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://android-sdk.is.com/com/ironsource/sdk/mediationsdk/7.7.0/mediationsdk-7.7.0.pom'.
> android-sdk.is.com**

React Native version: 0.73.1 My build gradle dependencies:
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appset:16.0.2' 
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.7.0' 
    


    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

project level build gradle:

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

package.json dependency for ironsource:
"ironsource-mediation": "^1.1.0",
